# I want to upgrade my current phone to either iphone6 or 6s should I wait until the iphone 7 has been shops for a week so that the prices drop>?

Tags: iphone

I'm currently in a pay monthy contract where I have an android Sony z5, I am contracted for another year. However I'm willing to pay the cancellation fee so that I can start a new contract with an iphone 6 or 6s.

I'm currently looking at deals for the 6 or 6s and they're in the margin of £40 per month (for the data / storage etc I will need)

My question is should I hold off upgrading my phone this weekend and wait until the iphone 7 is out in shops so that the 6 or 6s pay monthy deals may become cheaper?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

This ought to go without saying... Never buy a new anything right before the product line changes.

The 7 is going to be the same price as the 6S is today - so the price on the 6S will drop.
The 6S is also getting doubled RAM, same as the 7 range - so, depending on what stock they have left, you might get a double-discount if you get one of the older 'half memory' phones.

<sup>I do despair of my friend who thought she got a 'bargain' on an SE... yesterday :/</sup>